# Send function Rails jBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In a jbuilder file I am trying to do:

```
json.directives do
  json.edit_provider_path "{href: function(){return '#{edit_provider_path(resource)}';}}"
end
```

Which I receive in client as:

```
{edit_provider_path: "{href: function(){return '/providers/201/edit';}}"}
```

Is it possible to send a `function()` to  the client?, note that currently it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to send strings to client:

```
{a_key: "{\"href\": \"function(){return '#{edit_provider_path(resource)}';}\"}" }
```

Then, in coffeescript:

```
for key, val of res
  # key is a_key, and so on
  res[key] = JSON.parse(value)
  # res[key] is now {"href": "function(){...}"}
  for _key, _value of res[key]
    res[key][_key] = eval _value
    # res[key] is now {"href": function(){...}}
```

Ah, I forgot, `eval("function(){}")` does not work, so I had to wrap function:

```
eval("(function(){...})")
```

i.e.:

```
{a_key: "{\"href\": \"(function(){return '#{edit_provider_path(resource)}';})\"}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't allow functions, so I wouldn't expect jBuilder to support it. If you need to return full JavaScript to the client, a `js.erb` template is probably your best option.